# Subset Sum without duplicates

Tags: duplicates, subset, subset-sum

I know how to solve it using recursion. But the problem is the duplicates.

I need to get unique solutions every time.

Is there any way to remove the number that I used before from the array?

Here is my code:

```
static bool isSubsetSum(int []set, int n, int sum)
{
    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;
    if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
        return false;

    // If last element is greater than sum, then ignore it
    if (set[n - 1] > sum)
        return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum);

    /* else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following
       (a) including the last element
       (b) excluding the last element   */
    return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum) ||
            isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1]);
}
```

Comment: make array that keep used numbers and with conditional compare it against it.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ but i will need to compare the array with every number and that will take alot of time

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ i don't mean duplicates like 3 , 3 i mean when i use the 3 i shouldn't use it again in another set

Comment: what is your expectation to running time and how big data we talking about?

Comment: the data is about 10^6 , i'm not sure yet about the running time yet @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ